Windows: Use local PSDrives for non-powershell tools
I set up a temporary PSDrive to the top of a git directory:
New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Scope Global -Name Top -Root <repo top> -Description "Top level of repo"

This works great. I love being able to tab complete like cd Top:\..., but this doesn't seem to evaluate correctly for most commands. It seems like they don't realize that Top:\ is a drive and therefore attempt to resolve it relative to the current directory.
Trying git clean had it append as a relative path:
C:\repo\src\build > git clean -dfx Top:\
warning: could not open directory 'src/build/Top:/': Invalid argument

notepad also failed:
> notepad Top:\src\build\makefile

That gives a window that says "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."
It seems like PowerShell commands work fine. Get-Content and Get-ChildItem resolve the path correctly. Get-ChildItem even shows the Directory as the actual path, not Top:\....
Is there a way to get a local PSDrive to evaluate correctly for these other tools?

Because temporary drives are known only to PowerShell, you can't access them by using File Explorer, Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI), Component Object Model (COM), Microsoft .NET Framework, or with tools such as net use.

The mapping between Top and the mapped file system path only exists in-memory in your PowerShell session - it's not visible to any other process or the OS.
You can convert a PowerShell-specific path to it's underlying provider path, so you could do:
git clean -dfx (Convert-Path Top:\child\path)

Whether that's more or less readable that the alternatives (eg. git clean -dfx (Join-Path $repoRoot "child\path")) is subjective :)
